# How to group a dataframe by some transform of a column

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to group the rows of a dataframe not by the value of some column, but rather by the result of applying some function to the value of that column?  For example, to group the rows of the dataframe according to whether the value of a certain column is > 0 or ≤ 0.

Of course, I realize that one can always create an auxiliary column to hold the result of the transform, and use this auxiliary column as the argument to `groupby`.  My question here is whether there's a way to do the same thing without needing to create an auxiliary column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you give is pretty simple:

```
import numpy
import pandas

numpy.random.seed(0)
N = 15
df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'A': numpy.arange(N),
    'B': numpy.round(numpy.random.normal(size=N), 2)
})

print(df.to_string())


     A     B
0    0  1.76
1    1  0.40
2    2  0.98
3    3  2.24
4    4  1.87
5    5 -0.98
6    6  0.95
7    7 -0.15
8    8 -0.10
9    9  0.41
10  10  0.14
11  11  1.45
12  12  0.76
13  13  0.12
14  14  0.44
```

So then I can group by the comparison of column A to 10:

```
df.groupby(by=df['A'] < 10).sum()

        A     B
A              
False  60  2.91
True   45  7.38
```

The `by` statement can be more complex (i.e., return any number of values):

```
classifier = {0: 'old', 1: 'busted', 2: 'hotness'}
df.groupby(by=(df['A'] % 3).map(classifier)).sum()

          A     B
A          
old      30  6.12
busted   35  2.38
hotness  40  1.79
```